# Merging 2 json files with unique ID Powershell

Tags: powershell, object-graph

I need to combine 2 json files with powershell that both have unique ID.

**Json1**

```
   [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tags": {
        "tag1": "value1",
        "tag2": "value2"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": {
        "tag1": "value1",
        "tag2": "value2",
        "tag3": "value3",
        "tag4": "value4"
       
      }
    }
   ]
```

**Json2**

```
 [     
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "name1",
    "State": "Enabled"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Name": "name2",
    "State": "Disabled"
  }
 ]
```

**And the result should look like that:**

```
 [     
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "name1",
    "State": "Enabled",
    "tags": {
        "tag1": "value1",
        "tag2": "value2"
      }
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Name": "name2",
    "State": "Disabled",
    "tags": {
        "tag1": "value1",
        "tag2": "value2",
        "tag3": "value3",
        "tag4": "value4"
       
      }
  }
 ]
```

Also it would be nice if new file could be converted to csv i tried ConvertTo-CSV but output was unusable.

Comment: Your desired result is hierarchical - how would you want that translated to a flat format like CSV? What would the `tags` column look like?

Comment: i was wondering if there was a possibility of flatten it to column with header "tags" and tags could be just in a comma separated string like:
               "tags"
tag1:value1, tag2:value2....

Comment: That's definitely an option, just be aware that you'll required some custom code to "re-hydrate" the object-hierachy once you import the csv again - using `Import-Csv` for example, the imported cell value is just going to be the flat string `tag1:value1, tag2:value2, ...`

Comment: I won't need to import it again so that is not an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're only interested in matching pairs and both documents contain only objects with unique `ID` values, the easiest way is to pick any of them and built an index table - either manually using a hashtable/dictionary, or by using `Group-Object -AsHashtable`:

```
# create empty hashtable to store the objects from the tags documents
$tagStoreIndex = @{}

# read and parse json document, use Write-Output to enumerate the top-level array
Get-Content path\to\tags.json |ConvertFrom-Json |Write-Output |ForEach-Object {
  # store object by ID
  $tagStoreIndex[$_.ID] = $_
}

# alternatively use `Group-Object -AsHashTable` to construct the table
$tagStoreIndex = Get-Content path\to\tags.json |ConvertFrom-Json |Write-Output |Group-Object ID -AsHashTable
```

Now you can iterate over the objects in the second document and use the index table to quickly fetch the corresponding tags:

```
# read and parse second document
Get-Content path\to\states.json |ConvertFrom-Json |Write-Output |ForEach-Object {
  if ($tagStoreIndex.ContainsKey($_.ID)) {
    # construct new output object by attaching the tags from the other document
    $_ |Select-Object *,@{Name='tags';Expression={$tagStoreIndex[$_.ID].tags |ConvertTo-Json -Compress}}
  }
} |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Using `ConvertTo-Json` on the `tags` object gives you a string value that you can later convert back to the original `tags` object.

If you only need the tag values, change the property expression to

```
@{Name='tags';Expression={$tagStoreIndex[$_.ID].tags.psobject.Properties.Value -join ', '}}
```

If you want the tag names and values as bareword tokens, do:

If you only need the tag values, change the property expression to

```
@{Name='tags';Expression={$tagStoreIndex[$_.ID].tags.psobject.Properties.ForEach({$_.Name,$_.Value -join ':'}) -join ', '}}
```

Comment: Everything works but one more question, is there a way to also show the name of the tag, because right now there is only a value of a tag in the column

Comment: @Vauler Yes, I added another option at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

As a common solution in addition to the helpful answer from [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):
For the last months I have been busy creating a common [Object Graph Tools](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools) set as we dealing with similar queries in our company. This tools set is build on a general [PowerShell Object Parser](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools/blob/main/Docs/ObjectParser.md).
(Note that it is all still **under development**)

For this specific question you might use the included [`Merge-ObjectGraph`](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools/blob/main/Docs/Merge-ObjectGraph.md) cmdlet that (recursively) merges dictionaries (or `[PSCustomObject]`s) while respecting the given `PrimaryKey`(s):

```
Install-Module -Name ObjectGraphTools
```

```
$Data1 = ConvertFrom-Json $Json1
$Data2 = ConvertFrom-Json $Json2
,$Data1 | Merge-ObjectGraph $Data2 -PrimaryKey ID | ConvertTo-Json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "tags": {
      "tag1": "value1",
      "tag2": "value2"
    },
    "Name": "name1",
    "State": "Enabled"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "tags": {
      "tag1": "value1",
      "tag2": "value2",
      "tag3": "value3",
      "tag4": "value4"
    },
    "Name": "name2",
    "State": "Disabled"
  }
]
```

For flattening the object graph, you might play with [`$Object | Get-ChildNode -Recurse -Leaf`](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools/blob/main/Docs/Get-ChildNode.md)